# Using was twice in a single sentence

Tags: grammar

> The new president **was** invited to speak at a conference in Tokyo where he **was** to present his views on the shape of the world.

or

> The new president **was** invited to speak at a conference in Tokyo where he **has** to present his views on the shape of the world'

In the first sentence we have used *was* twice, while in second sentence one *was* and one has.

Which one is correct?

Comment: They are both grammatical, but they mean different things.

Comment: The first sentence is grammatical. It implies that the president's presentation never took place. The second sentence would be fine if you replaced *was* by *has been*. With that change, the president's presentation is expected (he *has to* present* his views) but has not yet taken place. As written, your second sentence does not seem grammatical to me. Perhaps @JasonBassford can provide his grammatical reading of it.

Comment: @RichardKayser No, the second sentence is fine just as it is. He *was* invited in the past, and he still *has* to present his views (it's an obligation—he's required to; he *must*) at some point in the future. There is no reason that the presentation itself also has to be in the past.